# Issue implementing a 4x1 multiplexer in verilog

Tags: system-verilog, icarus

I had an issue with a 4x1 multiplexer. The code is below:

```
module mux4x1( select, d0, d1, d2, d3, q );

    input[1:0] select; //CWP 0, CWP 1

    input[31:0] d0, d1, d2, d3;

    output[31:0] q;
    wire[31:0] q;
    wire[1:0] select;
    wire[3:0] d;

    case (select)
      2'b00 : assign q = d0;
      2'b01 : assign q = d1;
      2'b10 : assign q = d2;
      2'b11 : assign q = d3;
    endcase 

endmodule
```

Unfortunately it gives me the following errors when i try to use it elsewhere:

> testbench.sv:613: error: Unable to bind parameter select in `testModule.RWTest.mux1'
>   testbench.sv:613: error: Cannot evaluate genvar case expression: select

Line 613 is the `case (select) line`. I've looked into this quite a bit, and i've seen extremely similar code in other situations, so i'm not sure what the issue is exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `case` statement inside a procedural block like so:

```
always @(*) begin
  case (select)
    2'b00: q = d0;
    2'b01: q = d1;
    2'b10: q = d2;
    2'b11: q = d3;
  endcase
end
```

Remember, all logic needs to either be inside a combinational block using `always @(*)` like the above code or in a separate `assign` statement. Note that these should be "top level" within the module, ie no logic surrounding the `assign` like you have attempted to do in your code.

Note that as a result of this change, you will need to modify the type of `q` to be `reg` instead of a `wire` (also remember that `reg` type does not be a literal hardware register, its one of the more confusing things about learning Verilog unfortunately)

Comment: in this case `q` must be a `reg`, it cannot be a `wire`.

Comment: @Serge yes, I did make that note; though I really wish they had given it a better name as it really confuses beginners (thus the simplification in SV to make most things `logic` I guess)

Comment: @Serge this fixed my problem, thanks so much for the help and the clarification!